# Using Pexpect with Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-12.04, pexpect

After hours of research I have broken down to posting. I am trying to use the Pexpect module with python 3, which I am led to believe is possible from the [document page](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html) which does say it will run with python 3.2.

Things I have tried: I have tried many different ways of installing including downloading the source and running the command `sudo python3 setup.py install`. I have also tried installing it with *pip* and *easy_install* which is what the documentation suggest. It seems that everything goes off with out a hitch until I attempt to import the module in the pyshell. When I type `import pexpect` I get the error:

```
class spawn(object): 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pexpect/init.py", line 286, in spawn
  write_to_stdout = sys.stdout.buffer.write
AttributeError: 'PseudoFile' object has no attribute 'buffer'
```

I have also tried googleing the error with no luck. And I have tried using python 2.7 and it works fine. I have tried on multiple debian based operating systems: Ubuntu 12.04 and Kali with the same results.

I feel like there is something obvious I am missing, but I just don't see it. Any points in the right direction Or helping me understand the error message would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you importing this while in IDLE? Try opening a Terminal window and importing it from a plain Python REPL.

Comment: That works!!... Why does it work the terminal python and not in idle 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was [a bug](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/30) in Pexpect 3.0 which stopped it working if `sys.stdout` was replaced before it was imported. It looks like IDLE replaces stdout, so as you've found, it doesn't work in IDLE & Python 3.

The bug has now been fixed. I'll try to get a new version of Pexpect out in the next few days, and then you'll be able to use it from IDLE.